# How to play the bookmarked audiofile in media player?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have bookmarked audio file and storing into DB ,now i want to play same audio file it on media player but from that stopped point.(eg: bookmarked audio file at 0:18/5:35 want to play it from 0:18 till 5:35).How to do this ?

EDIT:

I want to play that audio files bookmarks stored in database needs to play in the media player. Is there any way to achieve this ?First i need to know that media player will support bookmarking to play  or not .If so how can i play it,please help me out to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Save this........

```
mp.pause();
length=mp.getCurrentPosition();
```

Restart with this........

```
mp.seekTo(length);
mp.start();
```

You will need some identifier to match it to the book though.

Comment: I have done bookmark in First activity ,storing that bookmarked time into DB.In second activity fetching that bookmarked time and trying to play when i click on play button but from that stopped point.I have tried your code but it wont work as per my requirement.Is there any other solution to overcome this problem?@digiholic

Comment: First i need to know that android media player will support bookmarking or not?If so where i am wrong (storing bookmark time into DB and fetching and trying to play it in other activity)?

Comment: I am not really sure whether there is a bookmark per say, but I use something similar to the above in my PopVideo app to add the face.  It saves the time you set (on a video) and plays it when using the non editor part of the app.  I know it is possible, just trying to hash out how it would work best for you.

Comment: ok.I will try to find out solution for it.Thanks for your reply.